# Log4Net Default behavior recording arguments

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, log4net

I have a few methods that take in a Json (Jarray) as a parameter in my payload. So the method signature may look like this:

```
[HttpPut("{id:int}/data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody] JArray jsonData, int id)
```

Log4Net records the payload in the log file. I'm trying to turn this behavior off and I was wondering if there was a way to do that?

I've played around with some configuration for the minimum logging but that doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can fulfill your desired behavior playing with the ASP.NET Core logging filtering.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                // Next line filters every "Microsoft" related message to be logged on any implementation of Microsoft Logging Providers.
                logging.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.None);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Just change the `Microsoft` text in order to filter the most fine-grained elements to get your desired behavior in place.